# Count immediate child div elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML node structure:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="baz">
    <div id="biz"></div>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

How do I count the number of immediate children of `foo`, that are of type `div`? In the example above, the result should be two (`bar` and `baz`).

Comment: I've added a jsperf test to see the speed difference between different approaches. see my answer below

Answer (score 359, accepted):

```
$("#foo > div").length
```

Direct children of the element with the id 'foo' which are divs. Then retrieving the size of the wrapped set produced.

Comment: I was just wondering on Friday how to count table columns with jQuery.  I'll have to try a similar approach: `$('#table > th').size()`.

Comment: Sometimes this does not work and you have to use $('#foo').children().size() which is faster anyway according to @mrCoder

Comment: If i want to use this instead of  #foo then.How to use this?

Comment: @472084 If you do it that way, it would count the "span" element too.  Notice how the question specifies he wants to count only the "div" elements, not all elements.

Answer (score 68):

I recommend using `$('#foo').children().size()` for better performance.

I've created a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-ele-size) test to see the speed difference and the `children()` method beaten the child selector (#foo > div) approach by at least **60%** in Chrome (canary build v15) **20-30%** in Firefox (v4).

By the way, needless to say, these two approaches produce same results (in this case, 1000).

[Update] I've updated the test to include the size() vs length test, and they doesn't make much difference (result: `length` usage is slightly faster (2%) than `size()`)

*[Update] Due to the incorrect markup seen in the OP (before 'markup validated' update by me), both `$("#foo > div").length` & `$('#foo').children().length` resulted the same ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LavMc/)). But for correct answer to get ONLY 'div' children, one SHOULD use child selector for correct & better performance*

Comment: though this question is asked sometime back, just wanted to share so that this could help someone from now

Comment: Where is filtering only 'div' children there?

Comment: `.length` is in fact the preferred method because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Yea, the child selector is correct because it uses native CSS selectors, so the selection is written in C++ rather than JavaScript... Quite a performance difference. This answer is easier to understand but a lot slower.

Comment: @manikanta Hey , very detailed anser. Sorry to bother, one question. If I do like `$('#extraLinks').children().size()` to count text boxes in a div (named extraLinks) why I get `4` when they are only 2. In general, I get the length multiplied with 2...Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 26):

```
$("#foo > div")
```

selects all divs that are immediate descendants of #foo
once you have the set of children you can either use the size function:

```
$("#foo > div").size()
```

or you can use

```
$("#foo > div").length
```

Both will return you the same result

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#foo').children('div').length
```

Answer (score 8):

In response to mrCoders answer using jsperf why not just use the dom node ?

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
var count = $foo[0].childElementCount
```

You can try the test here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-ele-size/7

This method gets 46,095 op/s while the other methods at best 2000 op/s

Comment: The OP asked for only div child elements

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#foo > div').size()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#foo > div").length
```

jQuery has a .size() function which will return the number of times that an element appears but, as specified in the jQuery documentation, it is slower and returns the same value as the .length property so it is best to simply use the .length property.
From here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/get-total-number-matched-elements-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

```
var divss = 0;
$(function(){
   $("#foo div").each(function(){
    divss++;

   });
   console.log(divss);  
});     
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar" class="1"></div>
  <div id="baz" class="1"></div>
  <div id="bam" class="1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

With the most recent version of jquery, you can use `$("#superpics div").children().length`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var n_numTabs = $("#superpics div").size();
```

**or**

```
var n_numTabs = $("#superpics div").length;
```

---

As was already said, both return the same result.

But the size() function is more jQuery "P.C".

I had a similar problem with my page.

For now on, just omit the > and it should work fine.

Comment: Descendant Selector will returns all the descendants of #superpics, including child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on, of that element, not just immediate children

Comment: more jQuery "P.C".  means ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div", "#superpics").size();
```

Comment: That counts **all** `div` descendants, not only the children.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for immediate child elements of type div

```
$("#foo > div")[0].children.length
```