# How can I count the number of children of a DOM element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to determine the number of images inside a certain div. I am fairly sure I have the code to select the elements I would like to count:

```
var imageCount = $("#work img").size();
```

And the div itself couldn't be simpler:

```
<div id="work" class="shown">
<img src="graphics/gallery/001.jpg" />  
<img src="graphics/gallery/002.jpg" />
</div>
```

But when I ask for

```
alert(imageCount);
```

It returns 0, not 2! What am I doing wrong? And yes, I am alerting inside a `ready` function so I know the elements are available...

Comment: [Works for me...](http://jsbin.com/uxene3) Whatever you're doing wrong, it's not evident to me from this question. What browser are you using?

Comment: For the record, your code works for me on FF and Chrome on Linux using jQuery 1.4.2. Maybe you are trying to alert it when the variable is out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var imgCount = $('#work > img').length
```

If this doesn't work, recheck your markup and make sure `img` elements are children.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like using (document).ready wasn't enough. When I put the same snippet of code into the body (instead of the head), boom, it worked like a charm. PS I'm still using my original code, the size() method and the ">" was not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using jQuery. You can do this:

```
var imageCount = $("#work").children("img").length;
```

Answer (score -3):

off the top of my head something like..

```
 $("#work").children("img").length
```

for more information see this question [count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery)