# jQuery count child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```html
<div id="selected">
  <ul>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to count the total number of `<li>` elements in `<div id="selected"></div>`. How is that possible using jQuery's `.children([selector])`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery

Comment: In pure JS, @Mo.'s answer is kind of low still, but use `element.childelementCount`

Answer (score 676, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) with just a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), like this:

```
var count = $("#selected li").length;
```

If you have to use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), then it's like this:

```
var count = $("#selected ul").children().length;
```

[You can test both versions here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VXg2D/).

Answer (score 38):

```
$("#selected > ul > li").size()
```

or:

```
$("#selected > ul > li").length
```

Comment: Just a note .size() has been deprecated in favor of .length

Comment: So it's the length that counts, not the size. ;)

Comment: @CJWEB: you are saying that `size` does no longer matter?

Answer (score 18):

fastest one:

```
$("div#selected ul li").length
```

Comment: This is not the fastest, in fact you slowed it down by adding `div` on there :)

Comment: It really depends on which browser you use. In many modern browsers, adding the element uses findByElement before finding by id or class, which is slower. Soon this will be a moot point either way though, because all DOM searches will be done using one native function.

In any case, a simple getElementById('selected') or $('#selected') would be faster at this point.

Answer (score 16):

```
var length = $('#selected ul').children('li').length
// or the same:
var length = $('#selected ul > li').length
```

You probably could also omit `li` in the children's selector.

See [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

Answer (score 16):

You can use JavaScript (don't need jQuery)

```
document.querySelectorAll('#selected li').length;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#selected ul').children().length;
```

or even better

```
 $('#selected li').length;
```

Answer (score 5):

It is simply possible with `childElementCount` in pure javascript

```js
var countItems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childElementCount;
console.log(countItems);
```

```html
<div id="selected">
  <ul>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

pure js

```
selected.children[0].children.length;
```

```js
let num = selected.children[0].children.length;

console.log(num);
```

```html
<div id="selected">
  <ul>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```