# distinguish parents li in CMS generated menu

Tags: menu, prestashop

I have auto generated ul li CMS menu (prestashop) and I need to distinguish which li items have another's descendants(sub-levels) and which haven't and distinguish their css to let people know which items contain another's items.

I wanted to do it through jQuery, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements

Comment: But how can I use this for multiple level menu with unknown depth of nested childern?

Comment: You can use a nested function to navigate through each of the li children.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still beginner in jQuery and I don't know if understand you. Could you show me a example?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could do:

```
jQuery('.sf-menu li').has('ul').addClass('has-submenu');
```

This will add the class has-submenu to all li elements with an ul inside. You can see how it works in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/59GFr/1/