# Sit divs next to each other that generate their own width to fill parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that's 960px wide and I have 5 divs inside that which I want to fill the width of the parent equally.

The reason I'm not just dividing 960 x 5 is because they will act as buttons and if I add or take one away I want them to adjust to the parent divs width.

I also want a 5px gap between each div so they're not touching.

This is my HTML set up at the moment:

```
<div class="parent">

   <a href="home.html"><div id="home">HOME</div></a>
   <a href="about.html"><div id="about">ABOUT</div></a>
   <a href="getoffer.html"><div id="getoffer">GET OFFER</div></a>
   <a href="testimonials.html"><div id="testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</div></a>
   <a href="contact.html"><div id="contact">CONTACT</div></a>

  </div>
```

Full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeQwc/)

Comment: One thing from looking at your fiddle, you have duplicated styles based on the `ID` of the elements, you should use a `class` instead of ID tags. i.e. `.button { }` and `<div id="home" class="button">`

Comment: @Nunners yea I always get confused which to use, no matter how much I read into class and ID I don't really understand the difference

Comment: @Adsy - it's really simple, ID is unique (only one per page), class is not unique.

Comment: @fatman but why use an ID over Class? What's so unique about it?

Comment: No real reason, you can never use ids and still make beautiful sites :), actually there is a big debate on the web whether to use id's or not

Comment: Yea, so basically you could just always use class and be ok?

Comment: that's right. Feel free to never use id's

Comment: Haha thanks fatman, I will now only use class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want, you can use this JQuery code:

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/WeQwc/8/)

```
var count = $(".parent a").length;
$(".parent div").width(function(){
    return ($(".parent").width()/count)-5;
}).css("margin-right","5px");
```

you can count children of parent element with `count = $(".parent a").length;`.
[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements/)

Comment: Doesn't work because if I add another div into the parent, it drops down underneath the others. I want all the divs to shorten to accommodate the new div

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
width: 18%
```

You can adjust the width accordingly as you add or remove.

Lastly, in your CSS you have a lot of repetition which can be further cleaned up by using a `class='button'`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WeQwc/1/

Comment: this isn't making the divs fill out to the edge of the parent div. There is loads of gap after the far right div