# Hide a <ul> when only one element in the <ul> exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, hide

Can someone tell me how to hide a `<ul>` when I only have one child `<li>` in it?

I have this code but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#flex-slider-carousel ul li").length();
  if($('#flex-slider-carousel ul li').length == 1){
 $("#flex-slider-carousel ul li").hide();}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting when you `console.log($("#flex-slider-carousel ul li").length())`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery count child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` is a property not a method. You can use the `filter` method:

```
$("#flex-slider-carousel ul").filter(function() {
   return $(this).children().length === 1;
}).hide();
```