# Count of nested ul-li children over multiple levels doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to show the count of all children elements over multiple nested levels beside all li elements which are dynamically generated.

Eg:

```
Z(8) 
    A(4) 
      B
      C(2)
        D
        E
    F(2)
      G
      H
```

**What i am getting now:**
[image]

**Code I used:**
Sample HTML:

```
<li class="li-item">
   <a href="#">B R(None)<span class="count-item" data-cnt="2">[2]</span></a>
   <ul class="sub-parent-ul 237">
      <li class="li-item">
         <a href="#">B R(None)<span class="count-item" data-cnt="3">[3]</span></a>
         <ul class="sub-parent-ul 246">
            <li class="li-item">
               <a href="#">Bhu Rik(None)<span class="count-item" data-cnt="3">[3]</span></a>
               <ul class="sub-parent-ul 258">
                  <li class="li-item"><a href="#">Kai Hiwatari(None)<span class="count-item"></span></a></li>
                  <li class="li-item">
                     <a href="#">B R(None)<span class="count-item" data-cnt="2">[2]</span></a>
                     <ul class="sub-parent-ul 263">
                        <li class="li-item">
                           <a href="#">Bhu Rik(None)<span class="count-item" data-cnt="1">[1]</span></a>
                           <ul class="sub-parent-ul 264">
                              <li class="li-item"><a href="#">B R(None)<span class="count-item"></span></a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".sub-parent-ul").each(function() {
        // reusabilty
        var context = $(this);

        // count and populate
        var count = context.children().length;

        context.prev("a").children().text('['+count+']');
        context.prev("a").children().attr('data-cnt',count);

    });

    $(".sub-parent-ul").each(function() {
        var context2 = $(this);

        // count and populate
        var child_count = context2.children().length;
        //check for inner ul
        var sub_count = 0;
        context2.children('li').each(function () {
            var context3 = $(this);
            if(context3.children('a').children('span').attr('data-cnt') !== undefined){
                sub_count += +context3.children('a').children('span').attr('data-cnt');
            }
            if(context2.hasClass('G52436')){
                console.log(context3.children('a').children('span').attr('data-cnt'));
                console.log(context3.children('a').children('span').html());
                console.log(context3.children('a').children('span'));
            }
        });
        // final count and populate

        var tot_count = child_count+sub_count;

        context2.prev("a").children().text('['+tot_count+']');
        context2.prev("a").children().attr('data-cnt',tot_count);
    });
```

It works for some levels but not everywhere. I am not sure where i am wrong. What's weird is, I have kept some console logs in the calculation logic which will get the complete count of child count. The js object shows the perfect count which i need, but when i select the attr from the object, it shows different value and that is driving me nuts.

[image: console log]
As you can see in the screenshot, the object shows the count as 2 but the value of attribute returns 1. It looks like it is ignoring the data-cnt of immediate child and getting the next child's data-cnt in some cases.

Can someone please identify the issue?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children

Comment: @DCoder That will count the immediate children, not the nested children. if you see my code given above, i have already used it to get count of immediate children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to be using recursion, but rather tries to enumerate a set depth (context,context2,context3).
One solution would be to use recursion within the function itself, the other is to use `find` instead of `children` to search multiple levels for all the children:

```
$(".sub-parent-ul").each(function() {
        var context = $(this),
            children = context.find('li'),
            count = children.length,
            a = context.prev("a").children();
        a.text('['+count+']');
        a.data('cnt', count);
});
```

Not entirely sure it's exactly according to your goal, but the outcome for the example html can be seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1L1zg5jx/1/)