# Why i get wrong number of child of div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var count = $("#abc").length;
console.log('Count : ' + count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;" id="abc"></div>
```

I get result = 1. Why is this? The div does not have any children? How can I fix this to get the correct number of children?

Comment: you are getting the length of the element with id abc add children to selector to count child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery count child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements)

Comment: $(selector).length is the number of elements selected by selector ... HTML elements do not have a .length property - what you see there is the length of the jquery object - absolutely nothing to do with the DOM

Comment: According the answer my problem cause i not add .children() to the syntax. thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the `#abc` element directly, hence the length property will always be `1`. If you want to get the number of children of the element, use `children().length`:

```js
var count = $("#abc").children().length;
console.log('Count:', count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;" id="abc"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var count= $("#abc").children().length;
console.log('Count : '+count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;" id="abc">

</div>
```

You are getting the length of the element with id `abc` 
Add children to selector to count child

Answer (score 0):

> Why i get result = 1, but the div not have any child?

Because the `.length` property of a jQuery object returns the number of elements in that jQuery object. That number is 1, because you selected that `div`.

> How to fix it to get correct number of child?

```
var count = $("#abc").children().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first find childrens of element using children() method and then calculate no of children`s using length.

so your expression should be

```
var count = $('#abc').children().length;
console.log('Count: '+count);
```