# Select input - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I would like to know the number of elements (in this case `option`) has my `select`

```
<select class="form-control" required>
    <option *ngFor="let numberDoor of car.doors" type="text">{{numberDoor .number}}</option>
</select>
```

That is the select but I would like to check first if it has more than an element, or less (0 or 1) doors

I guess the easiest way is using `Jquery` or `Javascript`

Comment: You can check the length of the array `<span>{{car.doors.length}}</span>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery count child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do something like *ngIF="scenario.lIntConf.length>30" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<select class="form-control" required *ngIf='car.doors.length'> 
    <option *ngFor="let numberDoor of car.doors" type="text">{{numberDoor.number}}</option>
</select>
```

If `car.doors` are empty, your select don't display.

Comment: Just add '*ngIf="car.doors.length > 2". This will display the select when there are more than 2 elements and the doors array. @MarioLópez