# count immediate child elements using jquery with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This question is similar to this one (but not exact):
[Count immediate child div elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery)

I have a bunch of lists that represent christmas presents for different people. 
As an example, this is a list of presents for one person. Note that new people can be added

```
<ul id = "presents">
<li id = "person1" >
<ul id = "presentsforperson1">
<li id = "present1" >
<ul id = "present1info">
<li> Present 1 </li>
<li> A New Pair of Shoes </li>
<li> $19.99 </li>
</ul>
</li>
<!-- More presents for person 1 can be added here dynamically-->
</ul>
</li>
<!-- More people can be added here -->
</ul>
```

Unlike the question posted, I have the object presentsforperson1 in a variable called drop (droppable). I was wondering what the correct syntax is for finding the number of presents person 1 has (in this case 1) with this variable?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 var numberofPresents = $(drop + "ul > li").length; //drop holds li#presentsforperson1 .droppable
 var numberofPresents = $(dropid + "ul > li").length; //dropID is $(drop).attr("id");
```

Comment: Do you just want the array length?

Comment: That's invalid HTML code. You can't have an UL as a child of an UL... The content model of an UL element are LI elements exclusively.

Comment: Also, you can't have a space between `<` and the tag-name...

Comment: @Hexxagonal - yes, i'd like to know the size of presentsforperson1 (the number of <li id = "present##">

Comment: Do your variables drop and dropId hold a text string or the jQuery object that contains those elements?  Also, could you add where these droppable classes are?

Comment: drop holds an object, dropid holds "presentsforperson1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person id is the id of the `ul` containing their presents then simply:

```
$('#personId > li').length
```

will do it.

**Update**

Or if the id is in a variable:

```
$('#' + personId).children('ul').length
```

You obviously could append the child selector to the selector string eg:

```
$('#' + personId + ' > ul').length
```

But personally I find the version with the .children call more readable.

Comment: do you know the syntax if the id is in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `drop` variable references a jQuery object:

```
var quantity = drop.children().length;
```

---

If it has the raw DOM element:

```
var quantity = $(drop).children().length;
```

---

If it is merely a string with the ID, with no ID selector syntax:

```
var quantity = $('#' + dropid).children().length;
```

---

Or you can do concatenation like you were:

```
var quantity = $('#' + dropid + " > li").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows (give your `li`s that represent a present a css class):

```
var presents = $('ul[id="person1"]').children('li.presentClass');

alert(presents.length);
```