# get the number of div in a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `main` Div of `id = "main_div"` and in this parent div I have 3 div of `class = "time"` then how to get the number of divs `class = "time"` in the div of `id = "main_div"`?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($('#main_div div.time').length)
```

The jQuery selector will return an array with all the divs, and .length property will return the number of elements in the array.

Comment: It is in javascript, but with jQuery. look at Kooilinc answer for pure javascript.

Comment: then why did u tag it with jquery ??

Comment: @manishjangir — That **is** JavaScript. It makes use of the jQuery library (which should be acceptable since you tagged your question with it!) and uses `console.log` for output demo purposes.

Comment: @manishjangir jQuery is a javascript library. It makes such stuff easy, whereas you would otherwise need an icky bunch of forloops.

Comment: @Manishearth — You don't need for loops to solve this problem without a library.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh yeah, `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @Manishearth or getElementById then getElementsByClassName.

Comment: @Quentin: Wait, that exists? I've been out of the loop for a while--IIRC one had to use a custom version beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll`. It returns a nodeList. The number of divs with className 'time' within div#main_div:

```
var nOftimeDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#main_div .time').length;
```

Comment: Not supported by IE7 or lower though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**jquery**

```
$('div#main_div').find('div.time').length
```

**pure javascript**

```
document.getElementById("main_div").getElementsByClassName('time').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .size() or length to get the number of matched elements

```
$("#main_div").find("time").length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('#main_div div.time').length)
```