# How to count child elements of a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to count the child elements in a `<div>` with jQuery:

```
<div id="home">
   <div>..</div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code I tried is:

```
console.log($('#home').length);
```

But it prints 0.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: There's a 87% chance you're calling the script before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @pawel nice stats! haha

Comment: You want to count elements by id? But you know that ids must be uniques of entire document?

Comment: I count element in a div with a id!

Comment: @Picco, No you dont, to count children use `$('#home').children().length` or `$('#home div').length`  https://jsfiddle.net/34gfLodo/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count immediate child div elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to count the `div`'s inside `#home`?

If so, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#home div').length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var divLength = $('#home').children().length;
    console.log(divLength);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in a document ready function,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#home').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` to count all elements in `#home` like following.

```
$('#home *').length
```

If you want to count only direct child the use direct child selector `>`.

```
$('#home > *').length
```

Answer (score 0):

After completion of loading of DOM, try this code.

```
    $('#home').children().length;
```